# Is it considered Ok to say “I’m glad to get acquainted with you”

Tags: idioms

Is it considered Ok to say in the end of a short or long meeting (business, date or whatever it is)  “I’m glad to get acquainted with you”?

Comment: I would usually advise English learners not to use "get ______" except for a few stock phrases like *get rich*, *get sick*, *get better*, *get to know*, because misuse of it is common among English learners and will make you sound non-fluent, but it's hard to state exactly what the rules are.

Answer (score 4):

It is grammatical and understandable, but usually not said.

To

> get acquainted

can have meanings of getting to know someone at a very close and intimate level, which in a business setting would be inappropriate (depending on the business) and on a date might be considered "*moving a bit fast*", of course additional/surrounding context will steer the interpretation

You might say

> I'm glad to *be acquainted* with you.

but that can sound *archaic* and is usually used when speaking in third-person

> I am *acquainted* with him.
>   It took some time for them *to get acquainted* with each other.

More modern day ways of expressing what you are trying to say might be

> It's very nice to meet you.
>   It's very nice to get to know you.

Comment: Good answer.  I would add another little twist as to why "acquainted" isn't a great word to use here.  "Getting acquainted" is often used to refer to becoming familiar with something very unfamiliar, an initial step before digging in and learning something.  Telling someone you're getting acquainted with them can sound like you think they are a "stranger in a strange land"; that their behavior, customs, thought process, or whatever, is very unusual or out of place and takes some getting used to.